# Single web.config file for all the environments and need to have environment variables for redirection rule path

Tags: docker, ordercloud, configbuilder

Planning to migrate to containers, wanted to maintain a single `web.config` file by using config builder all the app settings are being handled through environment variables along with this we have rewrite rules for redirection where we've different redirection rules for each environment and these are moved to a separate file like `DevRewriteRules.config`, `QARewriteRules.config` and `ProdRewriteRules.config` by referring the following [blog](https://ruslany.net/2010/05/storing-url-rewrite-mappings-in-a-separate-file/) and now our config file for rewrite section in web.config looks as below. Now in the below highlighted section, I want the rewrite rule config file to be changed based on the environment using the environment variable. Please suggest any better way to achieve this scenario.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore has [Rule-based configuration](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/rule-based-configuration.html).
But, the limitation is that these rules works only under `sitecore` node.

That is why, the best way to achieve it will be [good old `xdt:Transform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)).

I suggest you to have X different rewrite rules files:

- `ProdRewriteRules.config`
- `UatRewriteRules.config`
- `DevRewriteRules.config`

And transofrmation files for each of environment:

- `web.prod.config`
- `web.uat.config`
- `web.dev.config`

These files should rule to update rules file, similar to this:

```
<rules configSource="ProdRewriteRules.config" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes">
```

and you should run proper XDT transformation before deployment to each environment.

Comment: Thanks @Anton for the response but I'm looking for a solution using environment variables with the help of config builders.

Comment: @SudheerSuggu I am afraid that is not possible.

Comment: You can consider tokens in web.config and replace the tokens with actual values in your deployment pipelines

Comment: I totally agree with @SitecorePro , Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432799/how-to-set-and-read-user-environment-variable-in-azure-devops-pipeline